# nodejs buffer uint 32 from ruby?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to convert a Ruby program to NodeJS, but I seem to be getting stuck with buffers.

I have

```
rounds = header_bytes[120..-1].unpack('L*').first
```

In Ruby, which headers a buffer (header_bytes), and get's 120-124 (or in this case -1, which is remaining). Then unpacks it into an unsigned 32 bit integer.

I am trying to do the same thing in JS, but it can't seem to get it to work. I have

```
rounds = header.slice(120,124).toString('ucs2');
```

I've tried all the different formats in toString and nothing returns the same result as Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that header is an instance of Node's [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) then you  have a variety of functions for reading from a buffer as various sizes of integer, including

```
buf.readUInt32LE
buf.readUInt32BE
```

These both take an offset from which to read the bytes. The ruby `L` specifier means native byte order so depending on where this code is running you might need either of those functions, depending on whether you're on a big or little endian platform. For example on an x86 machine you'd do

```
header.readUInt32LE(120)
```

Protocols normally specify big or little endian (traditionally network byte order is big endian)

You can check the platform endianness with `os.endianness`

Comment: It should be noted that you can programmatically determine which function to use for the host system by checking the result of [`os.endianness()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/os.html#os_os_endianness).

Comment: But how can I read from 120 to 124? Do I need to read every character and append them to a string?

Comment: That's what the 120 parameter does - it says to start reading the unsigned integer from offset 120